# Javascript popup message didn't work in asp.net web application using MasterPage

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I have an ASP.NET Web Application.I am using `MasterPage` for some reasons. I want to show a `JavaSript` message box. When a user click on certain button control, then it should displays a message accordingly. Now when i do this without `MasterPage`, it works fine but when a `WebPage` is inherited from my `MasterPage` , i mean if the page is a `ContentPage`, then the `JavaScript` message box doesn't show. I want a general method for that so that i can reuse the method in other `content Pages`. 
Here is the Code.

```
 private bool CheckEmployeeNo()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Base.GetConnection))
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [TableEmployee] WHERE EmployeeNo=@EmployeeNo", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeNo", tbEmployeeNumber.Text);
                con.Open();
                int UserExist = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                if (UserExist > 0)
                {
                      string myMessage = "Here my msg goes..."; 
                      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Erroe " + myMessage + "');", true);
                    //lblMsg.Text = "Error: Message goes here.";
                    //lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;  
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: How about using `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` instead of `RegisterStartupScript`? Try using another key name if you have other registered script named as `alert`.

Comment: I have already done that like `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + myMsg + "');", true);` but still not showing. and what other key? like `success` or `failure`

Comment: Try another name for script name e.g. `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "success", "alert('" + myMsg + "');", true)`. Also check possibilities of client-side errors in console.

Comment: Its still not working. and in console it shows this error `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` here is link [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_parenthesis_after_argument_list] that directed me to this.

Comment: @PeterSmith can you eloborate more please

Comment: See if changing `"alert('Erroe " + myMessage + "');"` to `"alert('Erroe '" + myMessage + ");"` works.

Comment: @shahkalpesh not working :(

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Please help me sir

Comment: actually in mastepage you have to use Page.Clientscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Erroe " + myMessage + "');", true);
```

use this

Comment: You know what, i have spend 4 hours on this, tried everything i can, but all in vain. thank you so much Brother. :)

Comment: There was a time i waste so many hours too....its nice to be helpful atleast for others